# How to check user authanticaon on an asp page

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, login-control

I have three page which are  login.asp  , check.asp  and  admin.asp  . I want to block user to  access page just typing url like www.xxxxxxx.xxx/admin.asp   .How ı can do that ? is there a way to check redirected page.?  ı want just check.asp page can  redirect to admin.asp page

I know session solution but ı want to use another one

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to set some kind of authentication token which identifies that the user has been authenticated.  This is often done with either a cookie or a session value.  Then, on any page which requires authentication, you check for the existence of this token.

If the token (which can be as simple as a boolean IsAuthenticated value or an integer UserID value, or as complex as a complete User object with everything you need to know about that person, their roles, etc.) is valid, render the page.  If it is not valid, redirect or display a message of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")="" THEN
Response.write("Not accessable")
response.end
END IF


' Put this code on top of page , Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") which gives URL of previous page. so if any one directly paste URL in browser it will be blank , so we can track by this way.
```